# Python и Unreal Engine4. Возможно ли?

Tags: python, разработка-игр, unreal-engine-4

Изучая python появилось желание попробовать написать полноценную 3д игру (в идеале для App Store/Google play) на каком нибудь мощном игровом движке. Выбор пал на UE4, python он вроде поддерживает. Но я так и не смог найти вменяемых примеров написание полноценной игры используя только python. Может кто знает подобные примеры?

Comment: Есть [документация](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/Engine/Editor/ScriptingAndAutomation/Python/index.html) на эту тему. Так же мне попадались другие плагины на просторах GitHub связанные с Python для UE4.

Comment: слушай, как минимум это возможно. Так как даже в С++ есть возможность писать на Python